# How to use radio button to change another Button?

Tags: android

How to use radio buttons to decide which button any two buttons should appear where both buttons perform different task? In other words, if i change the radio button a button (normal button) should disappear and another button should take its place which performs another task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative layout and place one button on top of the other, then set one of them visibility to "Gone" or "Invisible" when your activity starts or directly in the xml file. Finally add a onCheckedChangelistener to your radio button and change the visibility of the buttons as you need.